# Facebook GRAPH API - user's friends list does not return any data except total count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created several test users in my App in Facebook developer account and granted all of them user_friends permission and also connected them together through 'Manage user's Facebook friends' option. However when I try to retrieve one of those user's friends list, it returns only total count of friend, but not their data .. Does anyone know why is that happening ? Thank you in advance..

[Test users list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXon5.png)

[me/friends request and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXqqD.png)

[Granted permissions to test users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJTOS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its a known bug of Facebook which has been reported here for app type Consumer/Business.

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/721152122632278/
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/615773773588521/

But you won't have any issue if your app time is Gaming Service, or you create a test app of your main app but don't forgot to create test users, assign them 'user_friend' permission and add them as a friend with each other. I followed the same process after going through alot of research and finally it worked.

Comment: I am facing same issue and my app type is not consumer/business. It is entertainment. I changed it to game but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Create a test app of your main app but don't forgot to create test users, assign them 'user_friend' permission and add them as a friend with each other. I followed the same process  after going through alot of research and finally it worked.